# Specific proof that the pullback of quasi-coherent sheaf is quasi-coherent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, exact-sequence, quasicoherent-sheaves

In Görtz-Wedhorn, the argument used to prove that the pullback of a quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ by the map $f: (X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a quasicoherent sheaf is in remark 7.23, and goes as follows:

> "Let $f: (X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. If $\mathcal{G}$ is a quasi-coherent module on $\mathcal{O}_Y$ it follows from $f^*(\mathcal{O}_Y) = \mathcal{O}_X$ and from the fact that $f^*$ is right exact and commutes with direct sums that $f^*(\mathcal{G})$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$ module."

I thought that his argument is meant to go as follows: because $\mathcal{G}$ is quasi-coherent, then for each $y \in Y$, there exists an open neighborhood $V \subseteq Y$ and sets I, J such that
$$\mathcal{O}_Y|_V ^{(J)} \to \mathcal{O}_Y|_V^{(I)} \to \mathcal{G} \to 0$$
Then, for each $x \in X$, consider a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ with this property. We have $f|_{f^{-1}(V)}^*(\mathcal{O}_Y|_V^{(J)}) = \mathcal{O}_X|_{f^{-1}(V)}^{(J)}$ - for the set $I$, analogously. Applying $f^*$ to the above exact sequence would give us:
$$\mathcal{O}_X|_{f^{-1}(V)} ^{(J)} \to \mathcal{O}_X|_{f^{-1}(V)}^{(I)} \to f^*\mathcal{G} \to 0$$
And this is an exact sequence, because $f^*$ is right exact.

Is this what the author meant? Because it seems to me that there is something wrong in this reasoning: the fact that $f^*$ is a contravariant functor would mean that the sequence would have its arrows reversed. If the author meat otherwise, what did he mean? Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: $f^*$ is not contravariant. The proof you lay out is just fine.

Comment: But the inverse image functor is, isn't it?. And the book even says that $(g \circ f)^* \mathcal{H} = f^*(g^* \mathcal{H})$ - which should be an evidence of contravariance.

Comment: I guess that the inverse image functor, and by consequence the pullback, always makes me kind of confused

Comment: No, the inverse image functor isn't contravariant either. Look at the definition again: it's the sheafification of $\lim_{V\supset f(U)} \mathcal{F}(V)$. If we have a map of sheaves $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ then we get a morphism of presheaves $\lim_{V\supset f(U)} \mathcal{F}(V)\to\lim_{V\supset f(U)}\mathcal{G}(V)$ by taking the limit of the maps $\mathcal{F}(V)\to\mathcal{G}(V)$. This is contravariant. Sheafifying and taking the tensor product preserve that.

Comment: Oh, I get it. It seems contravariant if you interpret $^*$ as taking a morphism of ringed spaces as an argument (whatever that means), but for a fixed morphism $f$, $f^*$ is a covariant functor in the category of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ modules.